# Unable to verify event hook

Tags: authentication, events, hook, okta, okta-api

I am testing out the event hook feature in Okta, but when I try to verify the endpoint, the message came out to be:

Unable to verify event hook. Could not deserialize response due to error at Line 1 Column 1

My functions will detect the X-Okta-Verification-Challenge header and outputs a response something like: : { “verification”: “ks58ZrThPLf22kTDavKLhm9aukKNECTmg–3gpsw” }

What am I doing wrong here?
The authentication field, secret and header fields are empty in the settings.
Thanks.

Comment: have you checked the documentation which says what happens during the verification phase? https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/event-hooks/#requests-sent-by-okta

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev  i did exactly the same

Comment: have you tried to curl to your endpoint with verification data to see what the response is from your hook?

Answer (score 0):

If you were [following their docs, using Glitch to write your service and remixing the first example](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/event-hook-implementation/nodejs/main/), it may have been failing for the same reason I've just seen:  The hook verification doesn't get sent to a specific GET route like `/userDeactivated` as described, but to the webserver root, and there's a route defined for that which serves a static index page. The verification request fails because the html response is not the JSON expected.